# eval and logical expression check

Tags: php, regex, logical-operators

I have to evaluate the dynamic expressions and based on the conditions, I need to show the other *div*.

My expression is:

```
{ [appln.module.name.VALUE] == 1 && [appln.module.name.VALUE] != EFT }
```

In case both of these expressions satisfy conditions, then the *div* must be shown. The value will be calculated based on the changes made.

Could someone help on this, of how to parse and evaluate the conditions dynamically?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What are the two "div" items being referred to? Why does it have a PHP tag? Why does it have a regex tax? What programming or templating language is even being used? Are you trying to write a custom parsing/evaluation engine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i found some solutions and implemented too. Using preg_match sort of things i used and fixed. Thanks

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: question is contradictory
so condition `(a == 1 && a != EFT)` can be easily replaced by just `(a == 1)`. 
I believe there is some mistake(typo?) in the text. 
Should it be `||` instead?

And what do yo mean under "parse and evaluate the conditions"? Are you creating template engine?

Comment: @skyboyer, `a == 1 && EFT != 1` if to be precise

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question boils down to "How do I show a DIV tag using PHP based on a conditional" To do this in PHP you could do something like the following...

```
<div id="YourDIV" <?php if ($ApplnModuleName != 1 || $EFT == 1){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>Your Content Goes Here</div>
```

The example above includes a negated implementation of your conditional. Both tests are required since $EFT could equal 1 which would need to hide the DIV.

An even better/cleaner way that would keep the contents of the DIV from being sent to the client would look like this...

```
<?php if ($ApplnModuleName == 1 && $EFT != 1) { ?>
    <div id="YourDIV">Your Content Goes Here</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The former example would allow you to turn the DIV on using Javascript in the client. The later example would save you bandwidth and prevent potentially sensitive data from showing up in the source of the HTML in the client.